# React Class component inside Function component is not re-rendering after state changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

99% of my app is functional components, but there's a legacy class component (`MyPDF`) nested inside a functional component (`MyApp`) that I have to use (it's too much effort to rewrite the class as a function). There is a state value, `url`, being passed to the class component from the functional component. However when then `url` changes in the parent functional component, those changes aren't propagating down to the class component, and it isn't re-rendering.

The class component is also written in TypeScript whereas the parent functional component is in JavaScript, if that matters at all.

**myapp.js**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import MyPDF from "./mypdf.tsx";

function MyApp() {
  const [url, setURL] = useState("https://initialpdf.com");
  const onClick = () => {
    setURL("https://newpdf.com");
  };
  console.log("url", url); // this url changes correctly
  return (
    <>
      <h1>This is my app</h1>
      <MyPDF data={url} />
      <p>PDF (Function): {url}</p>
      <button onClick={onClick}>Change URL</button>
    </>
  );
}
export default MyApp;
```

**mypdf.tsx**

```
import React from "react";

interface State {
  url: string;
}
class MyPDF extends React.Component<{}, State> {
  state = { url: "" };
  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
    this.state.url = props.data;
  }

  render() {
    return <div>PDF (Class): {this.state.url}</div>; // why isn't this.state.url changing?
  }
}
export default MyPDF;
```

**How can I get the class component to re-render & follow changes in the parent state?**

Comment: Use `this.props.data` instead of `this.state.url`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make the class component re-render when the data prop changes, you should use the componentDidUpdate lifecycle method to update the state when the prop changes.

```
import React from "react";

interface State {
  url: string;
}

class MyPDF extends React.Component<{ data: string }, State> {
  constructor(props: { data: string }) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { url: props.data };
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps: { data: string }) {
    if (this.props.data !== prevProps.data) {
      this.setState({ url: this.props.data });
    }
  }

  render() {
    return <div>PDF (Class): {this.state.url}</div>;
  }
}

export default MyPDF;
```